# How to find out if HX711(amplifier and 24-bit ADC) is damaged or not?

Tags: hardware, adc

I'm using this ADC with a load cell for weight measurement, I had 4 strain gauges and mounted them on a cantilever structure that I made out of acrylic sheet, used calibration program from here: https://github.com/olkal/HX711_ADC/blob/master/examples/Calibration/Calibration.ino,

followed the steps but it gave `calibration factor as 0.00` and the output was `NaN` or `inf` . I used another program from here: https://github.com/queuetue/Q2-HX711-Arduino-Library/tree/master/examples/simple_scale and the output was just hovering around `83868`. So I thought that the mounting was the problem and used a load cell (green label, CZL 601) with the above and found the same results by doing the above.

Then I thought maybe the ADC is at fault , measured the power output from Arduino to the board and it was around 5 V , but when I measured between the `E+` and `E-` , I got `0 V`. Since it is the excitation voltage to the bridge, it should be around 5V too right?

Is this the right way of checking the board?

P.S. I measured the four wires of the load cell and connected the opp. ends of the bridge to the E+ , E- , A+ , A- (order doesn't matter here right? connected the pairs that showed the rated resistance to E's and A's separately)

Here's a [pic][1] of the connections

Between White and green wire the Resistance is 350 ohm
Between Bk( connected in the board ) and the red it is 408 ohm
Between White and red it was 263 ohm
Between white and bk it is 320 ohm

Between bk(not connected in the board) and all others it is around 1 MOhm (so ignored that)
[1]: https://photos.app.goo.gl/4HEmZaN1EwZ7Mjur7

Comment: Start by checking the communication between the Arduino and the HX711. If that isn't working then you won't see anything useful. E+ won't be 5V until told to be by the Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko can you pls elaborate how do I do that! Also since I'm giving the 5V output of UNO to VCC of the HX711 module , I assumed E+ will be 5V ! (Just saw the datasheet , there's a transistor in between )

Comment: @Majenko do you mean reading the Dout pin by giving some voltage to A+ ?

Comment: Examine the DOUT and CLK pins using either a logic analyser or oscilloscope.

Comment: I don't have those things , its actually a small project that I'm doing for my home!  Any other method, that doesn't require more electronics!! Really appreciate the help, it's just that it's not a practical option for me! Thanks

Comment: Double check your wiring. Post a picture of your setup so we can check your wiring for you.

Comment: @Majenko Couldn't attach here , so attached as a link ...

Comment: Have you changed the pin numbers in the sample code to reflect the pins you are using in your setup?

Comment: Yes I did! I have gn it as 8 and 9 !

Comment: You wouldn't have been the first not to. So it sounds like *something* is dead. Your Arduino looks some what "battered". You may want to make sure those pins actually work by blinking an LED through them. If they do then it could be that the HX711 is dead. The only way to be sure without more kit is to replace it and see what happens.

Comment: Although... looking more closely at your photo - you haven't soldered the headers to your HX711 breakout board. You need to do that or they won't be making a good contact.

Comment: Thank you for your I/p. Since I just bought it , I thought I'll plug and see! I'll try to test out other possible causes and let you know!

Comment: @Majenko your observations were spot on! once I soldered the components everything fell in place, thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2):

Looking closely at the photo of your setup I can see that you haven't soldered the header to the breakout board. Whilst there are headers available that don't require soldering, and ways of making header connections that don't require soldering, this isn't either of those.

Without solder the connection to the board will be intermittent at best and non-existent in general.